# Angularjs ng-repeat animation with the same elements in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angularjs to add animation to a table when array in scope changes.
here is the HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in items track by $index" class="fade2">                                   
                <td >
                     {{ x }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
    <button ng-click="reset()">reset</button>       
</div>
```

and the javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['hello'];

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.items.push('hello')
    }

    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.items = ['hello','hello','hello','hello'];
    }
});
```

after add some CSS, it works fine if I click the button 'add' and 'reset', however, when I click the reset twice, there is no animation. Actually the array is updated but the elements in the $scope.items array doesn't change. How can I add a animation for this situation?

Comment: If you click reset twice is it not just the same array and doesn't change? Could try $scope.items = []; $scope.$apply(); $scope.items = ['hello','hello']
Feels hacky though.
Whats the CSS look like?

Comment: @fudy, because you are tracking `items` by `$index`, even if `$scope.reset()` is called multiple times to set a new array, as far as `ng-repeat` is concerned, the data has not changed (i.e. same number of items in the new arrays), thus it will not trigger a re-render. If you still want a workaround to force your animations, the gist of this question will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595656/angular-js-is-it-possible-to-re-render-ng-repeats-based-on-existing-scope-data

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would want the reset to animate every time but [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/hxADUz8hWAzB6bvjpCjd) could essential do it

```
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.items = [];
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.items = ['hello','hello','hello','hello'];
    },200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, it works, but it seems a little tricky.